# How to use Download Manager with Storage access framework / Mediastore

Tags: mediastore, android-download-manager, storage-access-framework, scoped-storage

I need to download a pdf file and then fire an intent so that other suitable app can show the file. Till now, I was using `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` of `DownloadManager` to set the destination of my download as a subdirectory of download directory. Then I used `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` to create the file and get the uri through `FileProvider` and ultimately fired the intent with `ACTION_VIEW`.

Now with scoped storage, `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` is deprecated. I was planning to use SAF/MediaStore but they give content uri which I cannot use to set destination for download in `DownloadManager`. Is there a way to resolve this? I was thinking to store the content uri that one can get through the `DownloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile` in shared pref and then use it to fire intent without needing `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`. But I want to avoid such 'hacks' if there is a compatible way of using DownloadManager within scoped storage compliance restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I used getExternalStoragePublicDirectory to create the file and get the uri through FileProvider and ultimately fired the intent with ACTION_VIEW.

No. That is not the way to go.

Instead you should register a broadcast receiver for ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.

In onReceive() you can obtain an uri for the downloaded file.

Use that uri with a grant read permission flag for your intent ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: Yes, I am using that now. However, when I need to open the pdf later (that is, not subsequent to a download in the same activity), one way could be store the content uri and filename map in shared pref. I am instead scanning MediaStore.Downloads table as the Download are visible to that table.