# How to download and immediately open this file in another application

Tags: java, android, firebase

Good day. I am creating an application that downloads a file from firebase. Next, this file will have to open in the application that is installed in advance on the phone. How can I find this file after installation and open it in a new application. Thanks for any answer. sorry for my English

Download code:

```
public void downloadFiles(Context context, String fileName, String fileExtension, String destinationDirectory, String url) {
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

     request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName + fileExtension);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

What i tried.
open code:

```
public void openFile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setType("file/*");
        File download = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"king.mcpack");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(download));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with"));
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67290251/how-to-use-download-manager-with-storage-access-framework-mediastore/67418513?noredirect=1#comment119172834_67418513